# How does VS Code get type hints?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was using `argparse` in a project when I noticed the following:

- VS Code shows type hints for the arguments of `ArgumentParser.add_argument`:

  ```
  add_argument(*name_or_flags: Text, action: Union[Text, Type[Action]]=..., nargs: Union[int, Text]=..., const: Any=..., default: Any=..., type: Union[Callable[[Text], _T], Callable[[str], _T], FileType]=..., choices: Iterable[_T]=..., required: bool=..., help: Optional[Text]=..., metavar: Optional[Union[Text, Tuple[Text, ...]]]=..., dest: Optional[Text]=..., version: Text=..., **kwargs: Any) -> Action
  param *name_or_flags: Text

  add_argument(dest, ..., name=value, ...)
  add_argument(option_string, option_string, ..., name=value, ...)
  ```
- The source code of argparse does not have these hints (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py ):

  ```
      # =======================
      # Adding argument actions
      # =======================
      def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
          """
          add_argument(dest, ..., name=value, ...)
          add_argument(option_string, option_string, ..., name=value, ...)
          """

          # if no positional args are supplied or only one is supplied and
          # it doesn't look like an option string, parse a positional
          # argument
  ```

How would I write a function in my own code that shows type hints in the same way (i.e. the function I write has *args and **kwargs as the arguments, but any user of the function can see the names and types of the expected kwargs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That type information comes from the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed):

> Typeshed contains external type annotations for the Python standard
>   library and Python builtins, as well as third party packages as
>   contributed by people external to those projects.
>
> This data can e.g. be used for static analysis, type checking or type
>   inference.

You can see the specific types for `add_argument` [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/410174d90e60cf350d79f865287e3cd9bf1b5b3f/stdlib/2and3/argparse.pyi#L53-L66):

```
def add_argument(self,
                 *name_or_flags: Text,
                 action: Union[Text, Type[Action]] = ...,
                 nargs: Union[int, Text] = ...,
                 const: Any = ...,
                 default: Any = ...,
                 type: Union[Callable[[Text], _T], Callable[[str], _T], FileType] = ...,
                 choices: Iterable[_T] = ...,
                 required: bool = ...,
                 help: Optional[Text] = ...,
                 metavar: Optional[Union[Text, Tuple[Text, ...]]] = ...,
                 dest: Optional[Text] = ...,
                 version: Text = ...,
                 **kwargs: Any) -> Action: ...
```

For your own code, you can just add those type hints in directly, unless you need to support older versions of Python (syntax available from 3.0 per [PEP-3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), `typing` module available from 3.5 per [PEP-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)).