# why suggestions not working in python function in vscode?

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

when I writing code in vscode there is no problem I've got suggestions as you can see below:
[image]

but as soon as I declare a function in vscode I've got ZERO suggestions! no methods no name nothing! as you can see:
[image]

how can I fix it I tried the user setting and other stafs but nothing changes! by the way I've installed pycharm and there no problem with that!

Comment: There is no link between `channels` the parameter to your function and `channels` the module level variable. You could try writing a call to the function. `vscode` might be able to see that and deduce what it happening. So is this `vscode` or `pycharm`?

Comment: @quamrana this is VS Code. they're saying pycharm is doing what they expect and VS Code is not.

Comment: I suspect this is because you haven't done anything at the function definition site to hint to pylance what the type of `channels` is. Try adding a type hint for the `channels` parameter. https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/. if that solves it, then dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60947145/11107541

Comment: @quamrana As you can see below the function I've written a call for, but still, the method suggestion is not working! and this is `VSCODE`

Comment: @starball - thank you so much I've given a type for a parameter that I passed to function and methods are working! but it is a little odd that without giving a type of parameter methods do not working there should be a solution rather than giving a type to the parameter!

Comment: I've made some changes and suddenly works!
first I disable [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance]`Pylacne`.
second I've installed pyright.
and third I've changed `python: language server` in the settings instead of Pylacne I've set it on default.

Comment: But what are those changes?

Comment: I've edited the comment! now you can know!